# Is GarageBand not part of OSX anymore?

Tags: garageband

I had OSX 10.5 and I remember GB was there though I never used it. Now I run 10.8 and it doesn't seem to be installed - I looked in the Appstore and it's listed as costing £10 (about $15).

I wanted to check it's definitely not available freely for my Mac before I figure out what I should use instead for my hobbyist "record playing for youtube" needs.

Comment: This question probably belongs on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OP _could_ keep it on topic as kind of a "[software-rec], free, with a preference for GB, and if not GB, then what for my specific and particular recording needs," kind of question... maybe?

Comment: @Josh Since we already have a [couple](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/539/an-open-source-sound-editor-but-not-audacity) [questions](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/software-for-live-multi-tracking-recording-mixing/1165#1165) regarding recording software, that would cause the question to be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @FriendOfGeorge, except it was closed as OT?

Comment: Duplicate, I can get behind

Comment: @Josh Sorry for the confusion.  I meant to say it is currently off topic, but if re-worded as you suggested it would be a duplicate.

Comment: @FriendOfGeorge, oh I see.  I understand :)

Answer (score 7):

GarageBand has never been part of OSX, but iLife has come bundled with most mac systems. If you did a clean install of OSX, you will lose iLife. To get iLife back, look for the additional applications disc that came with your mac, and install iLife from there.

Comment: hmm, I'll look into that. Would iLife that came with my Mac and 10.5 work with 10.8?

Comment: I have no idea.